# Kendo Grid: how to make datasource trigger update and create events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am starting to look at how I would get my grid edits back to a service via the datasource.

Following the documentation, I have set a local test data source as follows..

```
function getDataSource() {
var gridData = [
{
  col1: new CellData('1', 'data1-1'),
  col2: new CellData('2', 'data1-2')
  },
{
  col1: new CellData('3', 'data2-1'),
  col2: new CellData('4', 'data2-2')
  },
];

var dataSrc = new kendo.data.DataSource({
batch: true,

transport: {
  read: function (e) {
    e.success(gridData);
  },

  update: function (e) {
    // batch is enabled
    var updateItems = e.data.models;

    // This is not called

    // on success
    e.success();
  },

  create: function (e) {
    e.success(e.data);
  },
  destroy: function (e) {
    e.success();
  }
 }
});

 return dataSrc;
}
```

I have a toolbar setup (with the "Save Changes"), and this is calling the SaveChanges configuration event, how ever, just cannot see what else I need to do to get the following to occur..

1. Have the data sources update called
2. Mark the grid "on dirty" so that the red "edited" indicators on the edited cells disappear

I am having the same problem with the Add New record (though I can't get the grids "addRow" even to fire here)

I have the running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/zL46oz49/8/)

Any help would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the DataSource schema for this to work:

```
var dataSrc = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    batch: false, // true would mean transport functions get multipe models  in e.data 
    transport: {
        // ....
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: {
                    editable: false,
                    defaultValue: 0 // 0 == new / unsaved row
                },
                col1: {
                    editable: true,
                    // new items would have that using default add button
                    defaultValue: {
                        id: 0,
                        CategoryName: ""
                    }, 
                    fields: { id: { editable: true }, display: { editable: true }
                },
                col2: {
                    editable: true,
                    fields: { id: { editable: true }, display: {  editable: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also note:

- [grid.saveChanges](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-saveChanges) will sync the DS, so you don't need to do anything in the event
- There is no addRow event.
- The default "create" button will try to add an empty object; since you work with nested objects, you need to add the row yourself so you can initialize the properties; thus you need a custom button and bind your action manually

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zL46oz49/12/))

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for that.  Adding the schema and model makes the Save button do something. So looking at the sequence of updates and creates (trying to understand), first of all I wanted to get rid of the *batch mode* - I wish I hadn't included this  (updated example here (http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/r28vmg6f/4/) The weird thing is here,  is now if I update a cell, and then sit the Save changes, it just seems to call the create for each row in the grid (and never the update). Also, after this if we hit cancel, it seems to add rows (back). Is this what should be happening here?

Comment: oops, gave you a bad model definition; I'm kind of confused about the nested structure of your data and I'm wondering whether you're making things more complicated than they have to be with that (considering hte other questions as well)

Comment: you probably should consult this: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud

Comment: Hi Lars, I admit my example was getting confusing. I have redone it (http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/dmezscyh/3/) using some more concrete data . Each row represents a (very simple) booking or a car and trailer (with your mods) A car and trailer has a registration but we want to display a more meaningful display value. This reg and display value need to be kept together when selecting from the combo. The key thing missing (as you have above) was also a unique id for each record, so it appears to work without the nested schema fields (for the 2 tuples). Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Last piece of the overall puzzle here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515544/kendo-grid-how-to-update-data-source-from-code-when-the-row-changes)